# amazon ec2 and s3 setup

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am about to migrate a large web project (many sites using common data) to EC2 and i wondered what would be the best setup (I am very much a newbie with Amazon AWS).

The site pages are rebuilt by scripts once a week and the resultant static pages are served (currently about 7 to 10k views a day). Inbetween the weekly builds I would like to access the db to add/edit data.

I am thinking either EC2 + RDS or EC2 and S3 (S3 having the advantage of keeping a copy of the static pages too). Do these options sound reasonable, based on what I have mentioned?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using EC2 (experimtented with a few instance types just to learn cpu extra large worked best for our type of application), and rather than using RDS we extensively use EBS -
one EBS for running code, one EBS which holds mysql database files.
S3 is used for incremental backups mostly- as the EBS can be mounted on any other instance easily.

Comment: how did you determine which instance size was best?

Comment: based on your situation i did some research and found this site http://www.john-nousis.com/development/tutorial-running-a-phpmysql-server-on-ec2-with-ebs/ which has got me going. thanks